# How do I specify dtype str correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, genfromtxt

File is **utility.dat**

```
Name    D   L   J   H   E   M   RF  AF
line1   150 4.5 2.0 150 2   Copper  0.8 true
line2   140 4.5 2.0 140 2   Aluminium   0.8 true
```

My script is **script.py**

```
import numpy
configName = "utility.dat"
lines = numpy.genfromtxt(configName,
                         skip_header=1,
                         dtype=(str, float, float, float, float, float, str, float, bool))

print(lines[0])
```

My result is

```
('',  150.,  4.5,  2.,  150.,  2., '',  0.8,  True)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now how do I specify the **dtype** correctly? Because I don't want to give a size like ***"S12"*** or something because there is no way I will know how big this can get. I also don't want to use **dtype=None**.

Any other solution?

Comment: So you know one solution, even if you don't want to use it.  Another is `dtype=None`.

Comment: i also dont want to use `dtype=None` is there any other way?

Comment: Write you own csv loader.

Comment: A preliminary load of just the string columns with `usecols` will tell you the correct `S` length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i am not able to do this via NumPy i have moved over to Pandas and it worked for me.

I am new to Python and so still learning, but i get the idea that if i want to have a table of data with Float,String,Integers i am better off using Pandas and if i have pure table that is mostly Float and Integers i am better off using NumPy.

for now Pandas worked for me, and so moving on. Thank you